# WPF DataGrid Usercontrol Columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a Datagrid with Paging, but I haven't gotten that far. 
Right now I have this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleControls.UserControls.PageFilterGrid"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleControls.UserControls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="500"
Name="Ultra">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="{Binding ElementName=Ultra, Path=AutoGenerateColumns}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Ultra, Path=MyItemsSource}" />
</Grid>
```

The Codebehind for that control looks like this:

```
public partial class PageFilterGrid : UserControl
{
    public PageFilterGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemsSource",
    typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(PageFilterGrid));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GenerateColumns = DependencyProperty.Register("AutoGenerateColumns",
    typeof(bool), typeof(PageFilterGrid), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyUltraGrid = DependencyProperty.Register("UltraGrid",
   typeof(DataGrid), typeof(PageFilterGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new DataGrid()));

    public IEnumerable MyItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(PageFilterGrid.MyItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PageFilterGrid.MyItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public bool AutoGenerateColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(PageFilterGrid.GenerateColumns);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PageFilterGrid.GenerateColumns, value);
        }
    }
    public DataGrid UltraGrid {
        get
        {
            return (DataGrid)GetValue(PageFilterGrid.MyUltraGrid);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PageFilterGrid.MyUltraGrid, value);
        }
    }

}
```

My question is, if I dont want to autogenerate columns , how can i specify the columns without adding them in code behind? I want to add them to the grid like you would normally in XAML. Something like this below, but this doesn't work.

I've tried bringing back just the columns and setting that property, but that doesn't seem to work either for the XAML.

```
<controls:PageFilterGrid x:Name="myultra" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MyItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <controls:PageFilterGrid.UltraGrid>
            <controls:PageFilterGrid.UltraGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="amount" Binding="{Binding}" />
            </controls:PageFilterGrid.UltraGrid.Columns>
        </controls:PageFilterGrid.UltraGrid>
</controls:PageFilterGrid>
```

Comment: DataGrid has *a lot* of useful DP. If you derive your control from UserControl, you will have to duplicate them. Maybe `PageFilterGrid : DataGrid` will be simpler?

Comment: I thought about this, but I want paging which will be links under the grid, so I didn't want to have to make 2 controls?

Comment: visual appearance is very customizable in wpf - make a copy of DataGrid `Template` and modify to add links at the bottom

Comment: You can't set your UltraGrid property to anything else than a DataGrid because the type of the property is DataGrid. It is unclear what you are trying to do but your custom PageFilterGrid doesn't even have a Columns property so obviously it has no concept of columns...

Comment: @Ash Is it possible? Through Template only Visual Appearances are customizable. He wants to add page buttons, page lables, etc while keeping all functionality of DataGrid.